Relation of Constants to continued fractions
I've never posted on Stack Exchange before, but came across something interesting that I wanted to see if anyone knew more about. If you take a continued fraction using a function evaluated at the value equal to the step of the infinite fraction—such as $f(x) = x$ being
$$1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{4+\ddots}}},$$
and $f(x) = x^2$ being
$$1+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{9+\frac{1}{16+\ddots}}},$$—it approaches some constant ( ~1.43312 and ~1.24328 respectively for the examples above ), but there are also constants that when you take the infinite continued fraction of them approach the same number, such as for $f(x) = x$, the continued fraction of ~0.735352 being
$$0.735352+\frac{1}{0.735352+\frac{1}{0.735352+\frac{1}{0.735352+\ddots}}},$$
approaches the same number. I was wondering what relation this has to the function. I was also wondering why some functions approach either weirdly normal values like $x^{x^x}$ approaching $\frac{17}{16}$ instead of some irrational number or $x^{-x^x}$ oscillating between 17 and 1.
